# Does all function's domain stay the same\expands as we derivate them?

Tags: derivatives

Lets define a funciton $f(x)$ with a domain of, lets say $a>x>b$. If I derivate this function, it's domain will always stay the same or expand? Or it can be "reduced"? Is that mean that $f'(x)$ must be defined in the following domain?:

$$g>x>t$$ $$g \leq a$$  $$t \geq b$$

Comment: differentiate $|x|$ and try putting in $0$

Comment: The very definition of derivative implies the domain can't expand. And it can certainly be smaller, take $x\mapsto |x|$.

Comment: An example of another sort: The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I don't think $a<x>b$ means what you want it to mean

Comment: @Travis Bahhh, too complicated for me. Can you give me an example that is closer to high school math?

Comment: @Eminem fvel's example is about as simple as possible. In my example, the function is continuous nowhere, and so it certainly isn't differentiable anywhere either, that is, the domain of $f'$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, for example, the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$ on $\Bbb R$ for an example in which the derivative's domain is not the same as the original function's domain.

Recall that the definition of the derivative is $$f'(x):=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h,$$ if this limit exists. In order for $f'(x)$ to make any sense, $f(x)$ has to make sense first, *i.e.*: $x$ must be in the domain of $f.$

Comment: Do you mean $\mbox{dom}\, f' \subset \mbox{dom} \, f$ with your last sentence?

Comment: I would say $\operatorname{dom}f'\subseteq\operatorname{dom}f,$ for clarity, but yes.